# How do I make an html css <link> node use a relative URL

Tags: html

I have an HTML document with:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/theCss.css">`

However, when I load the HTML page, chrome requests (and my server receives) the path "/style/theCss.css" - which is an absolute path. Why isn't it respecting the path I have written as the href?

Comment: did you try `./style/theCss.css` ?

Comment: Have you tried setting the base URL in the head of your page with `<base href="https://www.yourwebsite.com/">`?

Comment: @Nidhin - I did. Same problem.

Comment: @Will, that is my current workaround. It doesn't solve the problem tho - I would like the browser to request the correct relative path without constraining myself to a particular base.